# Bring a selected ListView Item to the top

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I have listviews inside a pager adapter, and I'm trying to make it so when I click on an item inside my listview, it will scroll that item to the top. I have an onclicklistener to the item, but I'm not sure how exactly to implement the scrolling given what I have.

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        List<App> app = this.apps.get(position);

        ListView list = new ListView(this.activity);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        container.addView(list);

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use ListView's onItemClickListener.
Secondly, use the setSelected() method with the item's position (which you get on the listener).

Answer (score 0):

[smoothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

[setSelectedPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection%28int%29)